# SQL Server query formatting for optimizer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a a deeper question about the query engine. Is there ever a scenario where the two below queries would run differently? I haven't been able to find one in testing, so I am thinking that the query engine interprets them the same. I've always been taught to use an inner join, but I am interested in if my observation is always true, because the where formatting would be easier to read for certain scenarios.

```
SELECT s.Name, new.OpenDate, s.StoreOpenDate
FROM dbo.site s, #newSiteInfo new
WHERE s.Id = new.SiteId
    AND s.StoreOpenDate <> new.OpenDate
    AND new.OpenDate IS NOT NULL;

SELECT s.Name, new.OpenDate, s.StoreOpenDate
FROM dbo.site s
INNER JOIN #newSiteInfo new ON s.Id = new.SiteId
    AND s.StoreOpenDate <> new.OpenDate
    AND new.OpenDate IS NOT NULL;
```

In case it isn't clear, the difference is an inner join vs the same restrictions in the where clause.

Comment: They won't run differently, but that doesn't mean you should be using syntax that was superseded 27 years ago: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Especially as only the `CROSS JOIN` and implicit `INNER JOIN` syntax is "supported" in all **supported** versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Sample query plan: [link](https://imgur.com/sEyz3TL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer is smart enough to generate the same execution plan for both queries - however, the explicit join syntax is far better than the implicit join.

That being said, I totally agree with Larnu's comment - the fact that implicit joins are still supported (**Note:** For inner joins and cross joins only!) is not a good enough reason to use them.

Explicit joins are better than implicit joins in several ways:

1. Explicit joins provides a clear distinction between join conditions and filter conditions.
2. Inners join can easily be replaced to an outer (left, right or full) join simply by replacing (or adding) a keyword - implicit outer joins are no longer supported (they where deprecated in 2008 version, which ended it's extended support in July 2019).
3. Explicit joins are far less error prone - since the join condition is in the on clause, the compiler will not let you run a join query without specifying a join condition.
4. Explicit joins are far more readable and maintainable.

there are probably other reasons to favor using explicit joins over implicit joins which I didn't list here - but even this short list should be enough to explain why **you should never use implicit joins again.**